# MultipleGesture on same view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am adding two gesture on a view. One is tap gesture and second is swipe gesture. Whenever user tries to swipe the view , tap gesture method gets called (tap gesture gets detected). What could be the reason ? Tap gesture should get ignore in this case.

below is the code .

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGest = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(itemSwiped:)];
 swipeGest.direction =  UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp ;
[messageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGest];

UITapGestureRecognizer *gest = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(itemSelected:)];
[messageView addGestureRecognizer:gest];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your using multiple gesture on same view. this may over hide one another property .For Ex:  first gesture recognizer recognizes the gesture (tap in this case) it cancels all touch events. Therefore the remaining gesture recognizers will never finish recognition, and will never fire their events.

In order to add more than one UIGestureRecognizer onto the same view, you need to set the delegate property (`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`)

```
yourGesture.delegate = self

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
        shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{


 if (gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass: [UISwipeGestureRecognizer class] || gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]) {
            return YES
        } else {
            return NO
        }
}
```

Comment: I want TapGesture to be ignore in this case.

Answer (score 0):

use this delegate method to avoid other gesture

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

        if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {

            [otherGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:gestureRecognizer];
            return false;
        }else if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]]){
            [otherGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:gestureRecognizer];
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGest = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(itemSwiped:)];
swipeGest.direction =  UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp ;
[messageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGest];

UITapGestureRecognizer *gest = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(itemSelected:)];
gest.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[messageView addGestureRecognizer:gest];


-(void)itemSwiped:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
  NSLog(@"swipe");
}

-(void)itemSelected:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
  NSLog(@"tap");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change single tap to doubletap gesture. so you can be sure user only double tap or swipe. It is good advice from me please follow it.